# Pivot Query SQL Duplicating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have a temporary table like this.
[image]

Then I'm pivoting that table using following query and output attached.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
  SELECT * from  @tmpTable2
 ) AS SourceTable
 PIVOT
(
max(timec)
FOR eventb
IN (
[Veh Reg Time],[Fitness ok time],[RFID Issue time],[MG-IN],[WB IN],
[MG-OUT],      [WB OUT]
)
) AS PivotTableAlias
```

[image]

In here issue is for a one 'RegNo' there is multiple records. But I want only one row for a one 'RegNo'.
How can I achieve this?

Expected out put should be like this.
[image]

Comment: i think `DISTINCT` will help you OR `GROUP BY`

Comment: How can I use distinct for this query?

Comment: ok post your expected output result here

Comment: expected result attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
  SELECT regno,eventb,timec,rfid from  @tmpTable2
 ) AS SourceTable
 PIVOT
(
max(timec)
FOR eventb
IN (
[Veh Reg Time],[Fitness ok time],[RFID Issue time],[MG-IN],[WB IN],
[MG-OUT],      [WB OUT]
)
) AS PivotTableAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pt.regno, pt.rfid, MAX(vrt), MAX(fot), MAX(rit), MAX(MI), MAX(wi), MAX(Mo), MAX(wo) FROM (
SELECT *
 FROM (
  SELECT * from @temtable2 t
 ) SourceTable
 PIVOT
(
max(timec)
FOR eventb
IN('Veh Reg Time' AS vrt,'Ftness Ok time' AS fot, 'RFID Issue time' AS rit, 'MG-IN' AS mi, 'WB IN' AS wi, 'MG-OUT' AS mo, 'WB OUT' AS wo)
) PivotTableAlias) pt
GROUP BY  pt.regno, pt.rfid
```